# Search a substring with sql query

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, select, substring

In my SQLite database I have a column with a series of values like `#7 qsqjjsqdzdsql`. `qsqjjsqdzdsql` is variable. The column type is `TEXT`.
I want to extract the number from all rows, and then get the largest one.

First I thought the best solution is to do that with the `substring` function but the length of the number can vary. Maybe `regexp`, but I cannot find a suitable pattern (it begins with #[1-9]space)

EDIT:

For example, I have 4 rows in a column

```
#7 qslqsendds
#78 mdsldpedd
#3 dmsdlef
#6 sdefzmdsdos
```

I want to get only the largest number. For example, here it is `78`.
I want `78` (not `#78`, not `78 mdsldpedd`).

Comment: You can use the count () function to calculate rows in sql.

Comment: Do you want to extract the qsqjjsqdzdsql part? If yes then you can use `SUBSTRING(col1 FROM POSITION(' ' IN col1) + 1)` - see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a79fbcb442c2eee828a1f87daf9fc6e7. I have described all SQL functions compatible with the SQL Standard here: https://github.com/iwis/SQL-notes/blob/master/Functions.txt, and I think it is the best to use one of them.

Comment: Oh, you asked for SQLite not MySQL, then use some function marked with the L from my file. I.e. here, `SUBSTR` instead of `SUBSTRING`; and `INSTR` instead of `POSITION`.

Comment: Besides I don't understand what you mean here: "I want to extract the number of all rows to get the last big number."

Comment: No I want to extract the number atfer # of all row to get the last big number. Example: I have these rows : #7 qsqjjsqdzdsql,  #18 sdpsqsqs, #3 qkqsqsqmsndsjd. I want to extract 18

Comment: Your description fails to make much sense. Please add sample data and expected results to your question, [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: See my first post pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `instr` to find the position of the space, and then use `substr` to extract the number before it. Then you could cast it to an `int`, and query its `max`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(col1, 2, INSTR(col1, ' ') - 1) AS INT))
FROM table1
```

**[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2da12c749d6f8279292b451d7fa2a5ed)**

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is get rid of the leading `'#'` with [`SUBSTR(col, 2)`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr).
SQLite will convert implicitly a string like `'7 qslqsendds'` to a numeric `7` simply by adding `0`:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(col, 2) + 0) AS max_col
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=aea9dc7b56180ad46c2121f56ce3646f).